# Pagination with Jquery MySQLi?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, pagination

how to convert `MySQL` to `MySQLi` with PHP and jQuery.
If I run the file below using `MySQL` work but I want to use `MySQLi`, how to change it?

cek my file:
**pagination_class.php**

```
<?php class Pagination_class
{
    var $result;
    var $anchors;
    var $total;
    function Pagination_class($qry,$starting,$recpage)
    {
        $rst             =   mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
        $numrows        =   mysql_num_rows($rst);
        $qry            .= " limit $starting, $recpage";
        $this->result    =   mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
        $next           =   $starting+$recpage;
        $var            =   ((intval($numrows/$recpage))-1)*$recpage;
        $page_showing   =   intval($starting/$recpage)+1;
        $total_page     =   ceil($numrows/$recpage);

        if($numrows % $recpage != 0)
        {
            $last = ((intval($numrows/$recpage)))*$recpage;
        }
        else
        {
            $last = ((intval($numrows/$recpage))-1)*$recpage;
        }

        $previous = $starting-$recpage;
        $anc = "<ul class='pagination m_bottom_0 f_top_5'>";
            if($previous < 0)
            {                  
                $anc .= "<li class='disabled'>
                            <a href='javascript:;'>
                                <i class='mdw-icon fa fa-angle-left'></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>";
            }
            else
            {
                $anc .= "<li>
                            <a href='javascript:pagination($previous);'>
                                <i class='mdw-icon fa fa-angle-left'></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>";
            }             
            $norepeat = 2;
            $j = 2;
            $anch = "";             
            for($i=$page_showing; $i>1; $i--)
            {
                $fpreviousPage = $i-1;
                $page = ceil($fpreviousPage*$recpage)-$recpage;
                $anch = "<li><a href='javascript:pagination($page);'>$fpreviousPage </a></li>".$anch;
                if($j == $norepeat) break;
                $j++;
            }               
            $anc .= $anch;
            $anc .= "<li class='active'><a href='javascript:;'>".$page_showing."</a></li>";
            $j = 1;

            for($i=$page_showing; $i<$total_page; $i++)
            {
                $fnextPage = $i+1;
                $page = ceil($fnextPage*$recpage)-$recpage;
                $anc .= "<li><a href='javascript:pagination($page);'>$fnextPage</a></li>";
                if($j==$norepeat) break;
                $j++;
            }               
            if($next >= $numrows)
            {
                $anc .= "<li class='disabled'>
                            <a href='javascript:;'>
                                <i class='mdw-icon fa fa-angle-right'></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>";
            }
            else
            {
                $anc .= "<li>
                            <a href='javascript:pagination($next);'>
                                <i class='mdw-icon fa fa-angle-right'></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>";
            }               
        $anc .= "</ul>";
        $this->anchors = $anc;

        $this->total = "<div>Halaman : <strong>$page_showing</strong> dari <strong>$total_page</strong>. Total : <strong>$numrows</strong> records</div>";
    }
} ?>
```

and below file ***berita_view***
please check in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VkWnPUne)

Thanks.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php. You need to make a connection then change all `mysql_` instances to their `mysqli` equivalent. If you are having an issue with a particular function please specify that, as is this is too broad.

Comment: I already change `MySQL` to `MySQLi` but it's not work and error. cek error information here [image](http://prntscr.com/fc3zki)

Comment: Did you read the error message? You can't just add `i` and expect everything to work. View the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php, specifically `Procedural style only: A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init()`.